# SQL - Setting column entry to 0 if it equals NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sql-update

So in my table, I have a column that looks like this:

```
45
NULL 
234234
123
NULL  
NULL 
75
```

I want to set all the `NULL` values to `0`:

```
45
0 
234234
123
0 
0 
75
```

I tried this:

```
UPDATE TABLE comm_call_count c 
SET c.messageCountFri = 0 
WHERE c.messageCountFri = NULL;
```

and then I tried this:

```
UPDATE TABLE comm_call_count c 
SET c.messageCountFri = IFNULL(c.messageCountFri,0);
```

But neither worked. How would I do this?

Comment: Try `WHERE c.messageCountFri IS NULL`

Comment: Your 2nd script should've worked.  What happened?

Comment: The spurious keyword **`TABLE`** in the update statement causes a syntax error, doesn't it?

Comment: @PM77-1 Turns out I did something stupid and included `TABLE`. whoops, nvm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` is not a value, it is the lack thereof. Therefore, you cannot evaluate it with operators designed to compare values (such as `=` or `!=`). Instead, you need to check for it explicitly by using the `is` operator. Also note that the syntax is `update <table name>`, not `update table <table name>`:

```
UPDATE comm_call_count c 
SET    c.messageCountFri = 0 
WHERE  c.messageCountFri IS NULL;
```

Comment: My error was something stupid, but I didn't know you have to do `IS NULL`, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the keyword **`TABLE`** from your UPDATE statement. I don't think that is allowed there. (I never use the word `TABLE` in an update like that.)

Seems like that would throw a specific error, rather than just "not work".

Comment: Thanks! I just realized my mistake on `TABLE` about like 5 seconds before you posted haha. But yes, the second statement did work when I took about `TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try:

```
WHERE c.messageCountFri is NULL;
```

This may sound like a no-brainer, but make sure your fields can be null to begin with